# iTunes connect error when adding new iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-distribution

I am trying to add new iOS App to iTunes Connect.

I have all AppID , Development & Distribution Provision certificates for my iOS App.

I have tried different browsers and systems. but I keep getting this eror:
[image]

It's been 12 hours I am trying and keep getting this same response. It's my first time I am uploading any app to AppStore.

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052514/itnues-create-apss-happen-error-please-try-again-create-apss-please-try-again?noredirect=1

Comment: Ya, I think everyone is having this same issue,

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Does anybody know when it will be fixed?