# Unable to create new app in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

For two days, I'm trying to create a new app on iTunes Connect but I have always the same, not really verbose, error :

[image]

Is this a known bug ? Do I need to make anything or do I just have to wait ? I was not able to find anything about this problem so I'm a little bit lost. Thank you !

Comment: I think everyone is having this same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061489/itunes-connect-error-when-adding-new-ios-app#comment53946038_33061489 contact apple

Comment: Yes, it's fixed now. Thank you.